# Adding values to pd.dataframe as rows generated by while loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I faced an issue writing my first code in Python. I have a code which is generating values from while loop. My goal is to build DataFrame including column headers such as(`['Date','Rev Growth','EPS LTM','DPS LTM','EPS Growth LTM','EPS Growth - NTM','EV/EBITDA - LTM','PE LTM','PE NTM','PEG','FCF Yield NTM','Div Yield']`) and then to add values generated by the loop. I'm getting values using `print()` function, which means loop is working properly, but I stacked with the dataframe part.

```py
 while count < today_new:
    count = count + relativedelta(months=+i)

    gra1 = ek.get_data(instruments=mylist2,fields=field1, parameters=param)[0].iloc[0][1]
    gra2 = ek.get_data(instruments=mylist2,fields=field2, parameters=param)[0].iloc[0][1]
    gra3 = ek.get_data(instruments=mylist2,fields=field3, parameters=param)[0].iloc[0][1]
    if np.isnan(gra3):
           gra3 = "0"
    else:
        gra3
    gra4 = ek.get_data(instruments=mylist2,fields=field4, parameters=param1)[0].iloc[0][1]
    gra5 = ek.get_data(instruments=mylist2,fields=field5, parameters=param)[0].iloc[0][1]
    gra6 = ek.get_data(instruments=mylist2,fields=field6, parameters=param1)[0].iloc[0][1] / ek.get_data(instruments=mylist2,fields=field6_1, parameters=param)[0].iloc[0][1]
    if np.isnan(gra6):
           gra6 = "0"
    else:
        gra6
    gra7 = ek.get_data(instruments=mylist2,fields=field7, parameters=param)[0].iloc[0][1]
    if np.isnan(gra7):
           gra7 = "0"
    else:
        gra7
    gra8 = ek.get_data(instruments=mylist2,fields=field8, parameters=param2)[0].iloc[0][1]
    if np.isnan(gra8):
           gra8 = "0"
    else:
        gra8
    gra9 = ek.get_data(instruments=mylist2,fields=field9, parameters=param2)[0].iloc[0][1]
    if np.isnan(gra9):
           gra9 = "0"
    else:
        gra9
    gra10 = ek.get_data(instruments=mylist2,fields=field10, parameters=param2)[0].iloc[0][1]
    if np.isnan(gra10):
           gra10 = "0"
    else:
        gra10
    gra11 = ek.get_data(instruments=mylist2,fields=field11, parameters=param1)[0].iloc[0][1]
    if np.isnan(gra11):
           gra11 = "0"
    else:
        gra11
```

Comment: Those gra1, gra2,....,gra11 are the values you want to store in data frame with corresponding columns?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Count will be for Date and gra1 for Rev Growth, gra2 for EPS LTM, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, I would collect all the headers and their values in a dictionary and build the data frame. Here, I will show you a data frame with a single row containing some of the header and the random values. I will assume:

```
import pandas as pd
Count = 5
gar1 = 6
gar2 = 7
dictionary_to_store = {}
dictionary_to_store['Date'] = Count
dictionary_to_store['Rev Growth'] = gar1
dictionary_to_store ['EPS LTM'] = gar2
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary_to_store, orient = 'index').T
```

will give you the data frame in one line as follows

```
   Date  Rev Growth  EPS LTM
0     5           6        7
```

But when you have the index to append in  the dataframe you can use the following approach

```
import collections
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(dict)
d['a']['b'] = 1
d['c']['e'] = 4
d['f']['g'] = 7
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
```

It gives:

```
     b    e    g
a  1.0  NaN  NaN
c  NaN  4.0  NaN
f  NaN  NaN  7.0
```

or you can always do the transpose to flip the data frame

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').T
```

will give

```
     a    c    f
b  1.0  NaN  NaN
e  NaN  4.0  NaN
g  NaN  NaN  7.0
```

I think in your case you need to use the second approach and initialize the dictionary before your while loop and keep it updating. your keys will be the header and values are Count, gar1... Its always good to show the desired output and a sample input data in your question as well. Please let me know if it helped.

**#can you run the following**

```
dictionary_to_store = {}
while count < today_new:
    count = count + relativedelta(months=+i)
    dictionary_to_store['Date'] = count

    gra1 = ek.get_data(instruments=mylist2,fields=field1, parameters=param)[0].iloc[0][1]

    dictionary_to_store['Rev growth'] = gar1

    gra2 = ek.get_data(instruments=mylist2,fields=field2, parameters=param)[0].iloc[0][1]

    dictionary_to_store['column3'] = gar2

    gra3 = ek.get_data(instruments=mylist2,fields=field3, parameters=param)[0].iloc[0][1]



    if np.isnan(gra3):
           gra3 = "0"
    else:
        gra3
        dictionary_to_store['column4'] = gar3

    gra4 = ek.get_data(instruments=mylist2,fields=field4, parameters=param1)[0].iloc[0][1]

    dictionary_to_store['column5'] = gar4

    gra5 = ek.get_data(instruments=mylist2,fields=field5, parameters=param)[0].iloc[0][1]

    dictionary_to_store['column6'] = gar5
```

and so on. Then build the dataframe using

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary_to_store, orient = 'index').T
```

You might get only the last line, as each time when you run the loop the dictionary will get updated with last value in each key. To get rid of this you might need to use the iterable you have. This can be done by using the second approach I mentioned above. For example, for Date column, you can do following

```
dictionary_to_store = defaultdict(dict)

dictionary_to_store['your iterable']['Date'] = count
```

With the provided code, I am not sure what can be the iterable you use. You have used some extra function call relativedelta inside which you have updated 'i', not sure what that is.

Comment: Hi @hemanta, thank you for your help, however I'm not sure how should I write my code. Basically what I'm trying to do is to create DataFrame with the columns: Date, Rev Growth, EPS LTM etc and then add to DataFrame values generated by loop: count, gra1, gra2, etc.
Should I create dictionary and then store values there?

Comment: Yes, just run these small examples I wrote first then you will have an idea.

Comment: thanks a lot, It's working as expected!
I've used count as an index for my dataframe and skipped Date column.
When it comes to function  relativedelta, I'm not really sure but it allows to add one month to date using while loop. So output for index column (which is using count) looks like: 1990-03-01, 1990-04-01, 1990-05-01, etc.
ex. dictionary I've used: 'dictionary_to_store[count]['Rev Growth']=gra1'

Comment: Happy to help.Thanks.